# Last four items of the websql database

Tags: html, database, web-sql

This is my function for all the data from my database. I only want the last four data out of the database.

```
function spelerWeergeven()
{
    db.transaction(function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM speler', [], function (tx, results)
        {
            var len = results.rows.length, i;
            if(len > 0)
            {
                $('#spelerTabel').replaceWith('<table id="spelerTabel"><tr><th>Spelers</th></tr></table>');
                $('#spelerTabel').hide();
                for(var i = 0; i< len; i++)
                {
                    $('#spelerTabel tr:last').after('<tr><td>'+results.rows.item(i).naam+'</td></tr>');
                }
                $('#spelerTabel').show('slow');
            }
            }, null);
    }
    );
}
```

Does anybody know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM `speler` ORDER BY `id` DESC LIMIT 4;
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but it doesn't work. I replace the code 'Select * From speler' by 'SELECT * FROM speler order by primary_key desc limit 4;'

Comment: Check your database table and find that column then use it. If you can not find or doesn't exists you can try using datetime coloumn if it exists.

Comment: But i'm working with an websql database and i can't see my column. Only the table data on my page.

Comment: Whatever the database is, you will have a primary_column in this table 'speler', Take a place where you are inserting values or show schema for table.

Comment: This is the code where i create the table : tx.executeSql('CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS speler (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, naam)');           And this is the code  tx.executeSql("INSERT INTO speler (id, naam) VALUES (NULL, ?)", [speler]);
                }); Where the text input going in the database. Maybe this will help?

Comment: Why didn't you define a datatype for column `naam`?

Comment: I don't know, i used an example to make my own database. I have a another question, now the output is al list of 4 items in a table,('<tr><td>'+results.rows.item(i).naam+'</td></tr>'); do one of you know a specific code so that i can work with the last items from the database?

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
SELECT *
FROM `speler`
ORDER BY `id` DESC
LIMIT 4;
```

(The backticks (`) are used to prevent SQL from reading the words between them as a keyword. It's a good thing to keep that in mind, since there are many, many keywords in SQL.)

#### Edit:

Since you have created a table called **speler** with the columns **id** (which is the primary key) and **naam** using the query `CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS speler (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, naam)`, we know your primary key column is *id*.

PS: It's a good thing to let table names start with capital letter (*Speler*), by convention.

Answer (score 0):

This will do it server side:

```sql
SELECT TOP 4 * FROM 
speler
ORDER BY id DESC
```

Also pretty clean using Linq:

```
//dc would be a linq datacontext
string cmd = @"SELECT TOP 4 * from speler order by id DESC";
IEnumerable<speler> fourItems = dc.ExecuteQuery<speler>(cmd);
```